# Windows Live Error Cannot Synchronise

Tags: accounts

For a while now I have been unable to syncrhonise my "Windows Live" account. I get the following error when I view the account on the settings page:

> We're having a problem synchronising your information. Try again
>   later. Error code: 80070490

I am quite sure that the password is correct. The server is set to `m.hotmail.com` and I am using a Lumia 610 running Windows Phone 7.8.

Comment: Have you tried removing the account and adding it again?

Comment: Have you seen this answer from Microsoft?  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-sync/error-code-80070490-when-syncing-windows-live/0c5f4ebc-4afa-43a7-8a9d-2d8e7a7dac46

Comment: Neil: this is my primary account so cannot delete it without hard resetting the phone.
Max: didn't work.

Comment: I had the same problem a few days back but a simple restart did the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

It happened for me, I forgot what was the error message. Anyway it turned out to be the two steps verification thing. I created an App password but out of stupidity I deleted all my apps passwords in Hotmail's settings which caused the device to stop synchronizing. I created a new app password and updated the settings in my phone with the new password and it worked like a charm again. Maybe this is the case for you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the server name to `bay-m.hotmail.com`

Comment: Consider adding more detail to this answer. Alternatively, consider commenting on the question if you have a short suggestion.

Comment: Get the same error.